# In some dictionaries paradigmatic is more closely related to standard than to conventional,why?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am confused why some dictionaries show conventional and standard both as a synonym to paradigmatic while most only show standard as a synonym. Does standard and conventional means something different ?

Comment: Probably because standard and conventional can convey the same meaning. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/conventional

Comment: Please give relevant quotes, linked and attributed.

Comment: A lot of dictionaries don't even include synonyms (except where they serve as definitions), but even those that do, and indeed even specialised dictionaries of synonyms or thesauri, don't guarantee to be identical or to be equally comprehensive.  Also, very few words are exact synonyms.  "Standard" and "conventional" are sometimes interchangeable but not always.